# Mapping mvc application to subdomains using IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, c#-4.0, iis-7.5

I am not sure the best way to architect my IIS environment and MVC4 applications.

I have my standard marketing site on www.mydomain.com . This is an mvc4 site.

I have created a 2nd mvc4 application that I want users to be able to access via
www.theircompanyname.mydomain.com

I dont want to have to hardcode any subdomains as I need this to be as flexible as possible.

Can anyone suggest what I should be doing?

Comment: i think you are looking for multitenancy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for a multitenant application, varied on the subdomain.

You can simply pull the correct record from a data source of sorts based on the current subdomain.

Also, for ease of routing and building links, I'd recommend building a new RouteBase subclassed type, that once initialized with the route, would have the subdomain and the referenced client Identifier as a route parameter in the RouteData.Values collection.

This article talks about subclassing RouteBase for a subdomain:
[How to do Basecamp-style accounts in Asp.Net Mvc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386327/how-to-do-basecamp-style-accounts-in-asp-net-mvc)

This stackoverflow.com post has a wealth of links regarding multitenancy:
[What to keep in mind when developing a multi-tenant asp.net MVC application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963919/what-to-keep-in-mind-when-developing-a-multi-tenant-asp-net-mvc-application)