# How to create subdomain with username using C# and asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When a user registers with my site, they will get a url like this "http://username.mysite.com" to access their page/folder. How this is possible using C# and asp.net mvc.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What operating system / version of IIS are you hosting the site on?

Comment: Done all sork on subdomain in this..
link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39145229/how-to-create-dynamic-subdomain-in-mvc/52313487#52313487

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was also looking to implementing your scenario and have some links bookmarked. Maybe this will get you on your way until some SO superstar gives another complete sample ;)

<s>http://blogs.securancy.com/post/ASPNET-MVC-Subdomain-Routing.aspx</s> (link down)

> - Step 1: Custom RouteBase
> - Step 2: Create the Controller
> - Step 3: Register the Routes
> - Step 4: Subdomains on localhost IIS

At the end of the article, it also references another SO post:

[Is it possible to make an ASP.NET MVC route based on a subdomain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278668/is-it-possible-to-make-an-asp-net-mvc-route-based-on-a-subdomain)

It seems like a SO superstar has already answered the question :)

Answer (score 3):

Rather than have the username as a subdomain how about having it as part of the URL path. Would be a lot easier for you to implement.

```
www.mysite.com/users/ravi
www.mysite.com/ravi
```

Then you could tailor your View page dependent on the username.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into the [IIS API over at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524505.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I'd agree with @David (+1).  Not only would it be easier to implement but it would be much more consistant for your site in regards to analytics, stats and probably most importantly, **caching**!  There's probably several other reasons too!

Unless you want to treat each user as a client, which is different.  But if they are all in the same domain then I'd advise to go with @David's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create fake subdomains with a custom HTTPModule as stated [Here](http://forums.asp.net/p/1072886/1569066.aspx)