# Create subdomain for each registered user?

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to make an ASP.NET MVC route based on a subdomain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278668/is-it-possible-to-make-an-asp-net-mvc-route-based-on-a-subdomain)
>   [How to create subdomain with username using C# and asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437277/how-to-create-subdomain-with-username-using-c-sharp-and-asp-net)

How can I create a sub-domain for each user who is registering in my application?

For eg. my application is hosted at `www.xyz.com`
If a user with name "bsoft" registers in my app, I need to create a url for the user as `bsoft.xyz.com`.

Comment: I don't agree with the comments. The first question doesn't really have an answer, just some links for further research. The second question has a very good answer, but it's MVC related and OP might not mean MVC.

Comment: and I do not agree with the "urgent idea".

Comment: In my case 
    user1.domain.com 
    user2.domain.com 
etc goes to same place.. I dont want to have a copy of code in subdomains.. all have to use same code and db but with different url