# How to create dynamic subdomains asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

Whenever a new user is created, a subdomain should be automatically created.

```
user1.abc.com
user2.abc.com
```

**Is there a way to achieve this through code?**

**Update:**

To create a subdomain I goto `applicationhost.config` file and add:

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:1122:abc.localhost" />
```

I'm looking for a generic way to create sub-domain where I don't have to edit applicationhost.config manually.

**Update 2:**

How my question is different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1437277/3952692).
The step 4 of the answer accepted as right is relevant to my question and no explanation is provided for `Subdomains on localhost IIS`.

Comment: Pretty much anything CAN be done, the question really should be "Here is what I tried code" and "My current problems is..".state your issue.

Comment: There seem to be similar questions. LMGTFY 
Put this in your google search: "create subdomain for each user site:stackoverflow.com"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create subdomain with username using C# and asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437277/how-to-create-subdomain-with-username-using-c-sharp-and-asp-net)

Comment: @J.Loscos seems like the blogger is facing same issue that I am facing :) It says: `I haven't found a way to make my host accept a wildcard so I basically just added to entries in it`

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss please see updated question

Comment: you could use wildcard in your binding to catch all subdomains :
`*:1122:*.localhost`
The problem with localhost is that it's the host file that defines it and it doesn't accept wild cards so each subdomains has to be defined manually in it. But that's only an issue on localhost. In production environment you have DNS were you could use wildcards to redirect all subdomains to your application