# How can I re-route a specific subdomain request to a different ASP.NET MVC controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 web app.  It has a default home page that handles all requests to `http://www.mydomain.com` as well as `http://mydomain.com`.  I also have an MVC Area set up that can be accessed via `www.mydomain.com/Foo/Hello/` (where "Foo" is the name of the area and "Hello" is a controller in that area).

If someone makes a request to `foo.mydomain.com` right now, it will route them to the default home page controller.  I would like all requests to the foo subdomain root (eg. without a specific area/controller specified) to automatically be rerouted to the `/foo/hello/` controller.

Additionally, I want any requests to the "Foo" Area via the www subdomain to be redirected to the "foo" subdomain.  ie. I want all requests to `www.mydomain.com/Foo/Goodbye` to be automatically redirected to `foo.mydomain.com/Foo/Goodbye`

I have, of course, looked at lots and [lots of](http://blog.tonywilliams.me.uk/asp-net-mvc-2-routing-subdomains-to-areas) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278668/is-it-possible-to-make-an-asp-net-mvc-route-based-on-a-subdomain) [samples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243045/url-routing-across-multiple-subdomains)/[questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15234204/asp-net-route-to-mvc-or-api-by-subdomain), but none of them seem to address my exact issue.

I'm not sure if I should solve this issue with routes, route constraints, route handlers, etc.

Additionally: this application is hosted on ***Windows Azure Cloud Services***, so I don't have full control over IIS settings.

Answer (score 1):

> **In your Web Server, the Application Pool of your site must have Integrated PipeLine Mode as highlighted below..**

[image]

> **or you can find it through the Basic settings of your Application Pool  like below..**

[image]

> **Then I added the HttpModule in my sample MVC application**

**HttpModule**

```
public class MyModule1 : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += context_BeginRequest;
    }

    public void Dispose() { }

    void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!System.Web.HttpContext
                       .Current
                       .Request
                       .Url
                       .Authority
                       .Contains("foo.mydomain.com"))
        {
            string URL = 
                (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme + "://" +
                "foo.mydomain.com" + 
                HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath + 
                HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Query);
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 301;
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Status 
                                                    = "301 Moved Permanently";
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.RedirectLocation = URL;
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }
    }
}
```

> **Then i added some code n Web.config for my HttpModule**

```
<system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  <modules>
    <add name="MyModule1" type="rewrite.MyModule1" />
  </modules>
  <handlers>
    <remove name="UrlRoutingHandler" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>


<system.web>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="MyModule1" type="rewrite.MyModule1" />
    </httpModules>
</system.web>
```

> **Then in the host file I added the following code.**

```
127.0.0.1  foo.mydomain.com
```

> **Then I added the Bindings for my website**

[image]

Comment: I suppose this sort of answers my second requirement, although I was hoping to be able to do it using more of the native MVC routing rules.  The way you described, I would also have to confirm that the first subdirectory accessed contains "foo" (eg. I would have to inverse your request URL match and add the virtual directory: `host.Contains("www.mydomain.com/foo/")`  It should work, but seems kind of messy.

Comment: Also, I should mention that in order to properly detect the subdomain, I need to pull the HOST parameter from the HTTP headers.  Using Url.Authority does not work for me.  Additionally, I'm hosting this on Azure Cloud Services, so I don't have full control over IIS, although, I believe Integrated pipeline is the default.

Comment: To your first comment : If you pay attention to the condition, it will only update `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority` or Domain Name. That's it. Rest is in piece.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear, but I have dozens of other MVC Areas, but only this one (Foo) has its own subdomain.  So, I can't just route every request that isn't already for the foo.* subdomain over to the foo.* subdomain.  The code you provided would route requests for `www.mydomain.com/Bar/Hola` to the foo subdomain, when it should just stay on the www subdomain.  That is why I suggested that I need to also detect the /foo/ subdirectory request to identify that the target is the Foo area.  Like I said I would rather do this with native MVC Routing, but this should work...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**URL Rewrite**](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) module for IIS7+ to achieve what you described. Documentation is here: [URL Rewrite Module Configuration Reference](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference?amp;clcid=0x409).

Simplified example would be:

1. Rewrite URL so that foo.mydomain.com access /foo/hello (so no
   redirect)
2. Redirect URL www.mydomain.com/foo to foo.mydomain.com/foo

Add in your web.config, `system.webServer` node `rewrite` section:

```
...
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect mydomain.com/foo to foo.mydomain.com/foo" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="foo" negate="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="mydomain.com" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://foo.mydomain.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Temporary" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Rewrite foo.mydomain.com to access /foo/hello" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="foo.mydomain.com" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/foo/hello" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

You can also edit/view those rules in IIS Manager, using GUI. Click your web site and go to IIS section / URL Rewrite module. Bellow you can see 1st rule in GUI.

[image: URL Rewrite rule in IIS Manager]

Comment: Per one of my comments on @PKKG's answer, this application is all hosted on Windows Azure Cloud Services, so I don't have full control over the IIS settings.  Is there another way I can create these rules?

Comment: Googling for a minute, it seems that URL rewrite is installed on Azure. Did you try to add rules in your web.config?