# How to use a SubDomain as Route Value in MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

first:

I did read and tried to implemented [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278668) and [this](http://hanssens.org/post/ASPNET-MVC-Subdomain-Routing.aspx) and [that](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/05/20/ASPNET-MVC-Domain-Routing.aspx), but I failed completely :(

my route is like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "DefaultRoute",
    "{calurl}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { calurl = "none", controller = "Subscriber", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

and I'm trying to use as

```
"{calurl}.domain.com",
"{controller}/{action}/{id}"
```

so the routed value `calurl` would always come from the subdomain.

and I could have links like:

```
http://demo.domain.com/Subscriber/Register
```

as of today I have

```
http://domain.com/demo/Subscriber/Register
```

---

**What I have tried**

I tried to create my own `CustomRoute` using the example of the links above (all 3, one at a time), and I end up always screwing everything.

and I'm keep thinking that it's to much code just to change `RouteValue["calurl"]` to the subdomain.

> What/How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if Routing extends to the actual domain name, as the domain or sub-domain should'nt have any effect on the working of a site/application.

I would suggest building your own sub-domain detection on each request. This keeps Routing and the Sub-domain detection separate and will help with testing etc..

This may help:

```
public static string GetSubDomain()
        {
            string subDomain = String.Empty;

            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.HostNameType == UriHostNameType.Dns)
            {
                subDomain = Regex.Replace(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host, "((.*)(\\..*){2})|(.*)", "$2").Trim().ToLower();
            }

            if (subDomain == String.Empty)
            {
                subDomain = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Host"].Split('.')[0];
            }

            return subDomain.Trim().ToLower();
        }
```

Comment: testing is easy, just update the `hosts` file with any subdomain (like `demo.localhost`) you like :)

Comment: Indeed, I think my main point is separating the domain detection with the rouiting, something I found useful.

Answer (score 1):

If you have IIS7, why not use a URL Rewrite rule?

This would probably be better than doing a hack job with your routes, and IIS would do what it does best.

Probably something like this:

```
<rule name="rewriteSubdomains" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*).domain.com/(.*)" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="domain.com/{R:1}/{R:2}" />
</rule>
```

This way, your route will handle the subdomain correctly, as it comes into the app differently.