# Subdomain Points To Blog Folder (Non-MVC) on an MVC 3 Site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, subdomain, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an MVC 3 site that is working and currently quite basic.  There is a folder off of the root called Blog where I have BlogEngine.net setup.  Both work as I want.  I had to do the following code in the global.asax file to make sure that MVC would ignore any request going to the Blog folder as follows:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{folder}/{*pathinfo}", new { folder = "Blog" });

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home",
              action = "Index",
              id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );
}
```

What I am looking for is to be able to go to:   blog.mysite.com  and have it go directly to the /blog folder.  I have a Subdomain setup through my hosting provider.  However, I am not sure what to do beyond this to tell it to go anywhere.  When I currently go to blog.mysite.com, it just takes me to the home page.

I suspect I will have to add a MapRoute assume it will be smart enough to still Ignore the {folder} one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer to this question might help you along:
[Is it possible to make an ASP.NET MVC route based on a subdomain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278668/is-it-possible-to-make-an-asp-net-mvc-route-based-on-a-subdomain)