# MVC 3 Subdomain Routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes, subdomain

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to make an ASP.NET MVC route based on a subdomain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278668/is-it-possible-to-make-an-asp-net-mvc-route-based-on-a-subdomain)

In asp.net MVC 3 site i'd like to create online stores for users.
Any store that is created by user should have a URL like *"**shopname**.mydomain.com"*.

I tried some routing work but failed at all. I am researching for a solution but cannot find any proper solution.

My purpose is that; if I can add a route to manage any request that tries to find a subdomain I will check if it is a user online shop name and get the dynamic data on play.

Need routing help :) Thanks.

Comment: Check out answer of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278668/is-it-possible-to-make-an-asp-net-mvc-route-based-on-a-subdomain

Comment: Just so you are aware, this concept is known as Multi-tennancy.  Each domain is a different "Tennant", much like you have multiple tennants in an apartment complex.

Comment: +1 for SEO friendly question title

Answer (score 17):

I have found a very powerful way. So check this :)

First of all for application development server of visual studio you have to edit the 'hosts' file.

Open notepad as administrator. Add any name for your domain something like

127.0.0.1 mydomain.com
127.0.0.1 sub1.mydomain.com

and what you need to use on development.

After give a specific port number to your web project. For example "45499". By this way you will be able to sen request to your project by writing in browser :

mydomain.com:45499
or
sub1.mydomain.com:45499

That was the preparing step. Lets get on the answer.

By using the `IRouteConstraint` class you can create your route constrains.

```
public class SubdomainRouteConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    private readonly string SubdomainWithDot;

    public SubdomainRouteConstraint(string subdomainWithDot)
    {
        SubdomainWithDot = subdomainWithDot;
    }

    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        var url = httpContext.Request.Headers["HOST"];
        var index = url.IndexOf(".");

        if (index < 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        //This will bi not enough in real web. Because the domain names will end with ".com",".net"
        //so probably there will be a "." in url.So check if the sub is not "yourdomainname" or "www" at runtime.
        var sub = url.Split('.')[0];
        if(sub == "www" || sub == "yourdomainname" || sub == "mail")
        {
            return false;
        }

        //Add a custom parameter named "user". Anything you like :)
        values.Add("user", );
        return true;
    }
}
```

And add your constrain in any route you would like to use.

```
routes.MapRoute(
                    "Sub", // Route name
                    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                    new { controller = "SubdomainController", action = "AnyActionYouLike", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                    new { controller = new SubdomainRouteConstraint("abc.") },
                    new[] { "MyProjectNameSpace.Controllers" }
                    );
```

Put this routes before your default route. That's all.

In the constraint you may do anything like check for subdomain name is a client shop name or whatever.

Comment: Wow, just when I though MVC was cool enough, it goes and slicks it's hair and smokes a cigarette.

Comment: What's the purpose of SubdomainWithDot assigned in the constructor?

Comment: It was on middle of development state when I copied and pasted the code here, In there it is not working :) But the purpose is that : you pass the subdomain name you are looking for in there.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to add a dns entry for `*.mydomain.com` to point at the root application, then when handling the request in the root application, check the request host to determine which `shopname` is specified.

Comment: Thanks for answer...
Do you think
In MVC routing how should I code? And in local asp.net development server can I see the incoming request for shopname.mydomain.com

Comment: @Bahtiyar, I could just give you the code, but you haven't provided us an example of what you have tried so far.  I'll get you started, then when you run into trouble, edit your question by posting the code you have and where you get stuck, and we'll help you through.  You'll either want to 1) create a base controller that all of your controllers inherit from and override the `Initialize` function and find the sub domain in the request, or 2) create a custom route attribute which finds the sub domain in the request and sets it as a route value.  Both work fine, 1 is _easier_.