# mvc 3 url routing based on user's country selection to filter user specific data

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url-rewriting, url-routing

**I have a mvc3 application hosted say on  www.mywebsite.com , how can i  customize routing so that i can filter data based on specific country of the user and the urls will be like the below one's**

- [usa.mywebsite.com](http://usa.mywebsite.com)
- [uk.mywebsiate.com](http://uk.mywebsiate.com)

  based on the user's seclected contry. How can i acheive that using url routing?

**I have a mvc3 application hosted say on  www.mywebsite.com , how can i  customize routing so that i can filter data based on specific country of the user and the urls will be like the below one's**

Comment: solution is provided at the following thread... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436268/mvc-3-subdomain-routing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution is provided at the following thread... stackoverflow.com/questions/5436268/mvc-3-subdomain-routing