# Access Asp.net Mvc areas from different domain

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, appdomain, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have a question. I have 2 areas in my mvc application. And i want to access this areas from different domain. Example:
Areas/Management>>www.management.example.com
Areas/Site>>www.example.com

How can i do that? Can you give me starting point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find your answer at [MVC 3 Subdomain Routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436268/mvc-3-subdomain-routing)

It's about Sub-domain, but with a bit alteration you can use it for your purpose.