# ASP.NET MVC3: Routing a request based on the subdomain

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I'm managing a portal type website where authenticated users have an individualized 'homepage'.

```
http://www.myWebSite.com/MyHomePage
```

I'd like to understand how to implement that same functionality to a subdomain name:

http://MyHomePage.myWebsite.com

So requests that come via the **MyHomePage** subdomain will authenticate the user and then render the same page as if they used the longer URL:  *http://www.myWebSite.com/MyHomePage*

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new class called `YourDomainRoute` that inherits `Route` and simply convert the sub domain to a controller name (or whatever you like) in the `GetRouteData()` method.

You also need to override `GetVirtualPath()` if you want `@Html.ActionLink` etc to automatically use your custom route.

Answer (score 0):

You would do this with a custom RouteHandler. See [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/278668/759701).

There is also a similar blog post by [Tony Williams for MVC 2](http://blog.tonywilliams.me.uk/asp-net-mvc-2-routing-subdomains-to-areas/) (it should still apply)