# Change view location by domain in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have domain `domain1.com` with an alias `domain2.com`.

How I can change the location of views for `domain2.com`?

I want the default pages:

- for domain1 to be `webhosting disk/Content/Views/Index.cshtml`
- for domain2 to be `webhosting disk/Content/Views/Domain2/Index.cshtml`

How can this be implemented via global.asax and an MVC route?

Comment: Is it just the default pages that are different for the two domains? are the rest of the pages the same?

Comment: @Dallas No all views are different.

Comment: I found solution [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278668/is-it-possible-to-make-an-asp-net-mvc-route-based-on-a-subdomain

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why they can't be two sites? They can still be hosted on the same server with same ip using hostheaders.

You can extend the Razor View Engine. This is an example extending the view engine to [dynamically determining the view path](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/06/27/view-engine-with-dynamic-view-location.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Seems simple enough: write a domain aware `ViewEngine`. I'd recommend, however, abstracting out the logic of determining when/how to switch view into it's own interface; that way if you you decide to switch view on a cookie value, instead of URL, you can easily do so.