# Catch 2 different subdomain URLs by one application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need my web site to catch URLs like `mysite.com` and `a.mysite.com` as the same. By another words, requests to these URLs should be handled by single action controller and user should catch the same response from them.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into [Controllers and Routing](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs)?

Comment: As far as I know MVC routing can't help to set up such "cross-subdomain" mapping.

Comment: you could use something like [subdomain-routing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278668/is-it-possible-to-make-an-asp-net-mvc-route-based-on-a-subdomain)
and check the current url to generate the subdomain name based on that, just send it to the same place.

Answer (score 1):

MVC won't help you here--other than defining the default controller and action (route) when browsing to a site.

You will need to catch these hostname in your hosting environment. In IIS, I think you can use wildcards when creating a website. In your case, it would probably look like:

```
*.mysite.com
```

Your application would live inside this site, and anyone accessing it on an unexpected subdomain would see the same thing.

Comment: Can I set it up using `web.config`?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. Jamie Hutton's comment about subdomain-routing might be what you're looking for if you have to do it programmatically. Though, I would still do it at the host level.