# MVC 3 Redirect to Action on Subdomain

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, redirect, subdomain

I have a website I am developing (`http://www.mywebsite.com/`) that makes use of subdomains. Basically what I want is when you go to: `http://www.mywebsite.com/Redirect`, it redirects you to `http://blahblah.mywebsite.com/SpecificController/SpecificAction`.

I know about `Redirect`, but that doesn't let you send POST parameters (as far as I know), and `RedirectToAction` doesn't let you specify a subdomain.

Comment: Take a look at [this question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278668/is-it-possible-to-make-an-asp-net-mvc-route-based-on-a-subdomain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For subdomains in routes check this [guide to domain routing](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/05/20/ASPNET-MVC-Domain-Routing.aspx)

When you have it set up. for a specific redirection you can use this:

```
return RedirectToAction("SpecificAction", 
        "SpecificController",
         new { subdomain = "blahblah");
```

As for the post part, you can just use the TempData dictionary (TempData["varName"]) to pass the data to the next controller/action