# Domain dependent routing ASP MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have two domains:

mydomain.com 
and
mydomain.fr

They both correspond to the same IP address.

I want users typing mydomain.com to view page A (Controller = "Application" Action = "A" )
and users typing mydomain.fr to view page B (Controller = "ApplicationFR" Action = "B" )

I am using ASP.NET MVC 3 and the default route is mapped to page A.

How can I achieve this ?

---

EDIT:

I tried to use the example provided but it seems not to work.
Is it the right way to register the custom route ?

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.Add(new ExampleRoute());
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Application", action = "B", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by creating a new route and adding it to the routes collection in `RegisterRoutes` in your `global.asax`.

Check out this question: [Is it possible to make an ASP.NET MVC route based on a subdomain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278668/is-it-possible-to-make-an-asp-net-mvc-route-based-on-a-subdomain)

Comment: _Is it the right way to register the custom route?_ Not exactly. Look at this specific answer to see how to work with custom routes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2723863/290343