# How to route subdomains to areas of MVC3?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

how would I configure my area to use a subdomain as the route?

E.g. publishers.domain.com pointers to area publishers.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can go with this approach:

[Is it possible to make an ASP.NET MVC route based on a subdomain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278668/is-it-possible-to-make-an-asp-net-mvc-route-based-on-a-subdomain)

Or you can make a simple helper:

```
public IHtmlString SubUrl(this UrlHelper urlHelper, string subDomain, string controller, string action, object options) {
    return subDomain + urlHelper.Action(action, controller, options);
}
```

In the View: `Url.SubUrl("my.domain.com", ...);`