# MVC3 Routing: Match to any string

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes, url-routing, string-matching

Simple question:

How do I match a string in the MVC3 routing system?

Example:

```
{sub}.domain.com/{contoller}/{action}/{id}

sub = [Match any string here]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your question has been [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278668/is-it-possible-to-make-an-asp-net-mvc-route-based-on-a-subdomain).

Basically, to get to the {subdomain}.domain.com, the normal route handler won't look there, but you can create your own custom Route class which does, and register it in your Global.asax Application_Start().