# Use 2(or more) Database in one asp application and switch connection string

Tags: c#, asp.net, connection-string, multi-database

i have one ASP application and i want to use that for 2(or more) place and each of them has their Database , now is there a way to change connection string when user log in?
or anyway to change database for each user?

i saw this question before

> [How to setup single-code multiple-database ASP.NET SaaS application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758167/how-to-setup-single-code-multiple-database-asp-net-saas-application)

but i couldn't figure out how it works!

### please help me

EDITED:

I found a way for this problem
I saved my connection strings on database for each user, after identification i will figure out which connection string is for this user, and then assign that to my data sources an etc ...

saved connection string

```
"Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=DB;Data Source=."
```

ASP

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="DataSource" runat="server" ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

C#

```
DataSource.ConnectionString = "Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=DB;Data Source=.";
```

For Linq to SQL

```
DataClasses1DataContext m = new DataClasses1DataContext("Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=DB;Data Source=.");
```

i hope useful for other which has this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In multi-tenant SaaS solutions it's very common to have multiple connection strings depending on the user tenancy or account.

You simply need to stop storing the connection string in the `web.config` file and start building them dynamically at runtime, preferably through a helper class, based on your criteria (logged user, account, tenancy...).

Comment: Thanks, do you have any sample code for doing that pls?

Comment: That would really depend on your specific problem. I don't know if you use Entity Framework or vanilla SQL. You would have to post a code sample.

Comment: i think i found a way , check above