# ASP.NET define virtual subdomains programmatically?

Tags: asp.net, url, iis, virtual, routes

How can I define virtual sub-domains in my ASP.NET Web Application programmatically?

Is it possible via Route or any other kind of Virtual Url providers?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to make an ASP.NET MVC route based on a subdomain?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278668/is-it-possible-to-make-an-asp-net-mvc-route-based-on-a-subdomain)