# Can such Routing be done in MVC 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Can I have a path configured as :

```
        routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{id}.zeko.com",
        defaults: new { controller = "App",
                        action = "GetDetailsById", 
                        id = UrlParameter.Optional
                      }
               );
```

I want the id as a parameter to my method. Tell me where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok figured it out myself.....just we have to spilt the domain we have got after each id is created.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure that this is possible. I believe the routing engine in MVC does not handle domain requests by default. What you can do is add an IIS handler that processes the requests beforehand, or what I have done in Web Forms (and I am not exactly sure how you would accomplish this in MVC) is to call a method to strip out the subdomain in my **"Page_Load"** method and then work with that variable as required. Below is an example of the function I use, keep in mind my application only expects to work with a single subdomain such as **"subdomain.maindomain.com"**:

```
private static string GetSubDomain(Uri url)
    {
        try
        {
            string host = url.Host;
            if (host.Split('.').Length > 2)
            {
                int firstIndex = host.IndexOf(".");
                string subdomain = host.Substring(0, firstIndex);

                return subdomain;
            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }

        return string.Empty;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this post for you, however it requires knowing each possible subdomain in advance, where as my previous answer allows for dynamic subdomains. Hope these helped!

[Is it possible to make an ASP.NET MVC route based on a subdomain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278668/is-it-possible-to-make-an-asp-net-mvc-route-based-on-a-subdomain)