# Take whole URL as parameter in MVC 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to make an ASP.NET MVC route based on a subdomain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278668/is-it-possible-to-make-an-asp-net-mvc-route-based-on-a-subdomain)

My URL looks like

```
    http://Infosys-1234.teradata.com
```

Can I take the whole URL as a parameter by configuring my path as:

```
         routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{url}",
    defaults: new { controller = "App",
                    action = "GetDetailsById", 
                   // url = UrlParameter.Optional
                  }
           );
```

If not, suggest me an alternative. I want to take out Infosys-1234 as a parameter from the url.

Comment: http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/05/20/ASPNET-MVC-Domain-Routing.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
routes.Add("DomainRoute", new DomainRoute( 
    "{param1}.example.com",  "{action}/{param1}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", param1 = "" }  // Parameter defaults 
));
```

From
http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/05/20/ASPNET-MVC-Domain-Routing.aspx

Edit: Need to instead say param1 (parameter names)

If that doesnt work maybe this would be a better solution

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{param1}.mydomain.com",
    defaults: new { controller = "App",
                    action = "GetDetailsById", 
                    param1 = ""
                  }
           );
```