# How to use subdomain in Windows Azure?

Tags: azure, dns, azure-web-roles

I currently have my domain.com assigned to my azure website, but I'd like to know what I need to use subdomains.

I suppose I need to create a CNAME at godaddy. But what do I point it to? And how does each subdomain point to each folder in my solution?

Do I need web roles for this? I have no clue how to achieve this.

Note. I have a shared instance. And I'm already using a custom domain. All I want is to create a folder in my solution, and create apps inside it:

**Solution < ExampleFolder < ExampleApp**

And access it though **examplefolder.mydomain.com/exampleapp**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind multiple domains to a single Windows Azure Website.  You will then need to configure your routing within your application to redirect the traffic to particular folder and keep the URL's rewritten properly.

If you're using ASP.NET MVC, this task will not be super hard

Comment: Could you give me an example as to how to configure my routing to redirect traffic of a subdomain to one of the solution folders?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278668/is-it-possible-to-make-an-asp-net-mvc-route-based-on-a-subdomain

Comment: This did solve part of the problem. I still can't make it all work but thanks.