# ASP.Net MVC Allow Subdomains in URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This is a different question than the one here: [Is it possible to make an ASP.NET MVC route based on a subdomain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278668/is-it-possible-to-make-an-asp-net-mvc-route-based-on-a-subdomain)

I'm not looking to reroute based on subdomain, I just want to be able to include a subdomain and end up in the same place.

user1.mydomain.com should go to the same place as user2.mydomain.com

I can pluck the subdomain from the request to use it.

Currently a request to foo.localhost returns a 404 error.

Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this at the web host level. It's called site bindings in IIS, I'm not sure what Apache calls it.