# Create a Subdomain route in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to create a Subdomain route in asp.net

this is the current domain

```
www.example.com/default.aspx
```

and I am  trying to replace

```
"www" with a subdomain "foo"
foo.example.com/default.aspx
```

This is my current RouteProivder page

```
namespace Nop.Plugin.Wca.ExpertEstimator
{
    class RouteProvider : IRouteProvider
    {
       public void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
       {
            var route = routes.MapPageRoute(
               "ExpertEstimator",
               "/default.aspx",
               "~/Plugins/Wca.ExpertEstimator/default.aspx"
       );
    }

      public int Priority
      {
           get
           {
               return 0;
           }
      }
   }
}
```

Any input would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score -1):

You will find detailed information in the Article [Here](http://benjii.me/2015/02/subdomain-routing-in-asp-net-mvc/)

Earlier answers to simlar questions [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20609776/asp-net-mvc-subdomains) or [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278668/is-it-possible-to-make-an-asp-net-mvc-route-based-on-a-subdomain)

Comment: You should provide more information than just links. How does this help solve the OP's question?