# MVC5 attribute based routing for subdomains?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, attributes, asp.net-mvc-routing

How can one perform subdomain based URL routing in ASP.NET MVC5 **using attribute based routing**? I'm aware of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278668/is-it-possible-to-make-an-asp-net-mvc-route-based-on-a-subdomain?rq=1) but we're trying to move to a cleaner attribute based approach and I would like to move my route

from `http://domain.com/Account/Logout/`

to `http://my.domain.com/Account/Logout/`

Without subdomain routing, this standard code works:

```
[RoutePrefix("Account")]
public class AccountController : ApiController
{
    [Route("Logout")]
    public IHttpActionResult Logout()
    {
       // logic
    }
}
```

To add subdomain based routing, I wrote a custom attribute and a custom constraint. Basically replaced the `Route` attributes so I can specify the subdomain but my custom `SubdomainRoute` attribute doesn't work. My attempt is below. I presume a better implementation would also customize the `RoutePrefix` attribute to specify subdomains ...

### SubdomainRoute

```
public class SubdomainRouteAttribute : RouteFactoryAttribute
{
    public SubdomainRouteAttribute(string template, string subdomain) : base(template)
    {
        Subdomain = subdomain;
    }
    public string Subdomain
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
    public override RouteValueDictionary Constraints
    {
        get
        {
            var constraints = new RouteValueDictionary();
            constraints.Add("subdomain", new SubdomainRouteConstraint(Subdomain));
            return constraints;
        }
    }
}
```

### SubdomainRouteConstraint

```
public class SubdomainRouteConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    private readonly string _subdomain;

    public SubdomainRouteConstraint(string subdomain)
    {
        _subdomain = subdomain;
    }

    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        return httpContext.Request.Url != null && httpContext.Request.Url.Host.StartsWith(_subdomain);
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to make this work?