# Wanting To Redirect All Requests in asp.net MVC from given domain to specific view page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I want to have on my existing IIS web site an additional host header that will always redirect url's that come in with that domain to a specific mvc razor view page.  I've updated my global.asax as follows which kind of works but feels awkward and changes the URL to show the new URL which I don't want.

That is, I want all reqeusts that come in on the domain foo.org to redirect to the view /giving/svccgiving and for the users browser to continue to say foo.org

Here is the code I tried that partially works. any better suggestions?

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToLower().Contains("foo.org") &&
        !Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToLower().Contains("giving/svccgiving"))
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/Giving/SVCCGiving");
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried playing with routes instead?

Comment: I've thought about route, but I don't think that at the time the routes are established, there is any visibility of what domain is coming in.  That I believe is only known at the start of the request (I could be wrong)

Comment: Maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278668/is-it-possible-to-make-an-asp-net-mvc-route-based-on-a-subdomain

Answer (score 1):

The following works fine for me,

`this.Response.Redirect("~/Giving/SVCCGiving", true);`

because, the response end is true so further processing of the request does not take place