# MVC5 subdomain routing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-5, iis-express

I am putting together a simple website and I want to have a single subdomain. It will look like

www.sitename.com - a landing/marketing page
app.sitename.com - the meat of it

How can I do this in MVC5 with the least amount of pain? I have seen several solutions, such as [Is it possible to make an ASP.NET MVC route based on a subdomain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278668/is-it-possible-to-make-an-asp-net-mvc-route-based-on-a-subdomain) and http://attributerouting.net/#subdomains, but they seem to be much more complicated than I need and I am hoping someone has done it before.

Also, I am developing using IIS Express but some of the stuff I have found has said express can't handle this so I would like to know if that's possible as well.

Thanks

Comment: why don't you develop them as two different web projects?

Comment: IIS URL Rewrite module can support such, and both full IIS and IIS Express support it. http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

Comment: I like the idea of multiple projects, thanks