# Adding custom created route into route collection in Global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm quite new to asp.net mvc, so this could be quite trivial.
I'm trying to do asp.net mvc routing based on subdomain. I have been following this [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278668/is-it-possible-to-make-an-asp-net-mvc-route-based-on-a-subdomain/15287579#15287579) post. I created the class as said but I'm pretty confused about how to add it to routes collection in `Global.asax`. 
What i'm trying to accomplish is routing both `user1.exmaple.com` and `user2.example.com` to the same controller with parameters.
Here is the custom created route

```
public class ExampleRoute : RouteBase
{

    public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var url = httpContext.Request.Headers["HOST"];
        var index = url.IndexOf(".");

        if (index < 0)
            return null;

        var subDomain = url.Substring(0, index);

        if (subDomain == "user1")
        {
            var routeData = new RouteData(this, new MvcRouteHandler());
            routeData.Values.Add("controller", "User1"); //Goes to the User1Controller class
            routeData.Values.Add("action", "Index"); //Goes to the Index action on the User1Controller

            return routeData;
        }

        if (subDomain == "user2")
        {
            var routeData = new RouteData(this, new MvcRouteHandler());
            routeData.Values.Add("controller", "User2"); //Goes to the User2Controller class
            routeData.Values.Add("action", "Index"); //Goes to the Index action on the User2Controller

            return routeData;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
    {
        //Implement your formating Url formating here
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would usually add your custom route in App_Data\RouteConfig.cs file

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.Add(new ExampleRoute());
    }
}
```

And make sure it's called in your Global.asax Application_Start()

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```