# Separate routes between mvc 5 and api 2.2 in the same project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, routes

I have a project running mvc 5 and web api 2.2 together, however each one has their own routing sytem.

The problem is that both respond to api.domain.com and both respond to www.domain.com

So I need that the api.domain.com would not have anything to do with, for instance, api.domain.com/blog, which is a url that should only belong to www.domain.com/blog. Same way I should not be able to access www.domain.com/api/...

I was thinking about checking the url in the Application Requet and run an if statement there, however it does not sound right to me.

Is it a matter of splitting them into two separate projects under the same solution and cross reference the projects/libraries?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to make an ASP.NET MVC route based on a subdomain?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278668/is-it-possible-to-make-an-asp-net-mvc-route-based-on-a-subdomain)

Comment: separate the projects in the same solution :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the IIS URL Rewrite module to rewrite requests to `api.domain.com/...` to `/api/...` and `www.domain.com` to `/web/...`.  Now you can have entirely separate routes within the application.

Or you could create a custom action filter that checks the domain and apply that to each class or method to constrain it to only respond to that domain.  Or course you'd need a separate action filter for MVC and WebAPI but that's another story ...