# Create subdomain on the fly like blogger.com using asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, subdomain, asp.net-mvc-routing, wildcard-subdomain, mvcroutehandler

I want to create sub domains on the fly for each of my identity users (AspNetUsers). You can see this kind of feature available in blogger.com.

I have list of sub domain names in the database

```
Users={"abc", "xyz","blah"}
```

My original website is like this

```
http://mywebsite.com
```

The above users should access my website like below

```
http://abc.mywebsite.com
http://xyz.mywebsite.com
http://blah.mywebsite.com
```

I can do this in the web.config for the above 3 users. But users table will change frequently. So I would like to create sub domains on the fly for each user available in the `Users` table.
How can we achieve this using Asp.Net MVC?

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/30933162/1743997

Comment: Done all sork on subdomain in this..
link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39145229/how-to-create-dynamic-subdomain-in-mvc/52313487#52313487

Answer (score 4):

Maarten Balliauw has posted an excellent solution with a downloadable demo to this issue titled [ASP.NET MVC Domain Routing](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/05/20/ASPNET-MVC-Domain-Routing.aspx). Note that the demo doesn't upgrade correctly to recent versions of Visual Studio, but there aren't many files that are required to use this method so reverse engineering is not that painful.

### DomainRoute.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace MvcDomainRouting.Code
{
    public class DomainRoute : Route
    {
        private Regex domainRegex;
        private Regex pathRegex;

        public string Domain { get; set; }

        public DomainRoute(string domain, string url, RouteValueDictionary defaults)
            : base(url, defaults, new MvcRouteHandler())
        {
            Domain = domain;
        }

        public DomainRoute(string domain, string url, RouteValueDictionary defaults, IRouteHandler routeHandler)
            : base(url, defaults, routeHandler)
        {
            Domain = domain;
        }

        public DomainRoute(string domain, string url, object defaults)
            : base(url, new RouteValueDictionary(defaults), new MvcRouteHandler())
        {
            Domain = domain;
        }

        public DomainRoute(string domain, string url, object defaults, IRouteHandler routeHandler)
            : base(url, new RouteValueDictionary(defaults), routeHandler)
        {
            Domain = domain;
        }

        public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            // Build regex
            domainRegex = CreateRegex(Domain);
            pathRegex = CreateRegex(Url);

            // Request information
            string requestDomain = httpContext.Request.Headers["host"];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestDomain))
            {
                if (requestDomain.IndexOf(":") > 0)
                {
                    requestDomain = requestDomain.Substring(0, requestDomain.IndexOf(":"));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                requestDomain = httpContext.Request.Url.Host;
            }
            string requestPath = httpContext.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath.Substring(2) + httpContext.Request.PathInfo;

            // Match domain and route
            Match domainMatch = domainRegex.Match(requestDomain);
            Match pathMatch = pathRegex.Match(requestPath);

            // Route data
            RouteData data = null;
            if (domainMatch.Success && pathMatch.Success)
            {
                data = new RouteData(this, RouteHandler);

                // Add defaults first
                if (Defaults != null)
                {
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> item in Defaults)
                    {
                        data.Values[item.Key] = item.Value;
                    }
                }

                // Iterate matching domain groups
                for (int i = 1; i < domainMatch.Groups.Count; i++)
                {
                    Group group = domainMatch.Groups[i];
                    if (group.Success)
                    {
                        string key = domainRegex.GroupNameFromNumber(i);

                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(key) && !char.IsNumber(key, 0))
                        {
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(group.Value))
                            {
                                data.Values[key] = group.Value;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Iterate matching path groups
                for (int i = 1; i < pathMatch.Groups.Count; i++)
                {
                    Group group = pathMatch.Groups[i];
                    if (group.Success)
                    {
                        string key = pathRegex.GroupNameFromNumber(i);

                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(key) && !char.IsNumber(key, 0))
                        {
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(group.Value))
                            {
                                data.Values[key] = group.Value;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return data;
        }

        public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
        {
            return base.GetVirtualPath(requestContext, RemoveDomainTokens(values));
        }

        public DomainData GetDomainData(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
        {
            // Build hostname
            string hostname = Domain;
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> pair in values)
            {
                hostname = hostname.Replace("{" + pair.Key + "}", pair.Value.ToString());
            }

            // Return domain data
            return new DomainData
            {
                Protocol = "http",
                HostName = hostname,
                Fragment = ""
            };
        }

        private Regex CreateRegex(string source)
        {
            // Perform replacements
            source = source.Replace("/", @"\/?");
            source = source.Replace(".", @"\.?");
            source = source.Replace("-", @"\-?");
            source = source.Replace("{", @"(?<");
            source = source.Replace("}", @">([a-zA-Z0-9_]*))");

            return new Regex("^" + source + "$");
        }

        private RouteValueDictionary RemoveDomainTokens(RouteValueDictionary values)
        {
            Regex tokenRegex = new Regex(@"({[a-zA-Z0-9_]*})*-?\.?\/?({[a-zA-Z0-9_]*})*-?\.?\/?({[a-zA-Z0-9_]*})*-?\.?\/?({[a-zA-Z0-9_]*})*-?\.?\/?({[a-zA-Z0-9_]*})*-?\.?\/?({[a-zA-Z0-9_]*})*-?\.?\/?({[a-zA-Z0-9_]*})*-?\.?\/?({[a-zA-Z0-9_]*})*-?\.?\/?({[a-zA-Z0-9_]*})*-?\.?\/?({[a-zA-Z0-9_]*})*-?\.?\/?({[a-zA-Z0-9_]*})*-?\.?\/?({[a-zA-Z0-9_]*})*-?\.?\/?");
            Match tokenMatch = tokenRegex.Match(Domain);
            for (int i = 0; i < tokenMatch.Groups.Count; i++)
            {
                Group group = tokenMatch.Groups[i];
                if (group.Success)
                {
                    string key = group.Value.Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "");
                    if (values.ContainsKey(key))
                        values.Remove(key);
                }
            }

            return values;
        }
    }
}
```

### DomainData.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MvcDomainRouting.Code
{
    public class DomainData
    {
        public string Protocol { get; set; }
        public string HostName { get; set; }
        public string Fragment { get; set; }
    }
}
```

### LinkExtensions.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MvcDomainRouting.Code;

namespace System.Web.Mvc.Html
{
    public static class LinkExtensions
    {
        public static string ActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string actionName, bool requireAbsoluteUrl)
        {
            return htmlHelper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, null, new RouteValueDictionary(), new RouteValueDictionary(), requireAbsoluteUrl);
        }

        public static string ActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string actionName, object routeValues, bool requireAbsoluteUrl)
        {
            return htmlHelper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, null, new RouteValueDictionary(routeValues), new RouteValueDictionary(), requireAbsoluteUrl);
        }

        public static string ActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, bool requireAbsoluteUrl)
        {
            return htmlHelper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, controllerName, new RouteValueDictionary(), new RouteValueDictionary(), requireAbsoluteUrl);
        }

        public static string ActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string actionName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, bool requireAbsoluteUrl)
        {
            return htmlHelper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, null, routeValues, new RouteValueDictionary(), requireAbsoluteUrl);
        }

        public static string ActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string actionName, object routeValues, object htmlAttributes, bool requireAbsoluteUrl)
        {
            return htmlHelper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, null, new RouteValueDictionary(routeValues), new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes), requireAbsoluteUrl);
        }

        public static string ActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string actionName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes, bool requireAbsoluteUrl)
        {
            return htmlHelper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, null, routeValues, htmlAttributes, requireAbsoluteUrl);
        }

        public static string ActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues, object htmlAttributes, bool requireAbsoluteUrl)
        {
            return htmlHelper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, controllerName, new RouteValueDictionary(routeValues), new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes), requireAbsoluteUrl);
        }

        public static string ActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes, bool requireAbsoluteUrl)
        {
            if (requireAbsoluteUrl)
            {
                HttpContextBase currentContext = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
                RouteData routeData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(currentContext);

                routeData.Values["controller"] = controllerName;
                routeData.Values["action"] = actionName;

                DomainRoute domainRoute = routeData.Route as DomainRoute;
                if (domainRoute != null)
                {
                    DomainData domainData = domainRoute.GetDomainData(new RequestContext(currentContext, routeData), routeData.Values);
                    return htmlHelper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, controllerName, domainData.Protocol, domainData.HostName, domainData.Fragment, routeData.Values, null);
                }
            }
            return htmlHelper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, controllerName, routeValues, htmlAttributes);
        }
    }
}
```

### Edit to Global.asax (or in more recent versions of MVC, these go into `AppStart\RouteConfig.cs`)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
using MvcDomainRouting.Code;

namespace MvcDomainRouting
{
    // Note: For instructions on enabling IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode, 
    // visit http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801

    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.Add("DomainRoute", new DomainRoute(
                "home.example.com",                                     // Domain with parameters
                "{action}/{id}",                                        // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
            ));

            //routes.Add("DomainRoute", new DomainRoute(
            //    "{controller}.example.com",                             // Domain with parameters
            //    "{action}/{id}",                                        // URL with parameters
            //    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
            //));

            //routes.Add("DomainRoute", new DomainRoute(
            //    "{controller}-{action}.example.com",                             // Domain with parameters
            //    "{id}",                                        // URL with parameters
            //    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
            //));

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",                                              // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
            );

        }

        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
    }
}
```

Also see a gist with this solution (and discussion) [here](https://gist.github.com/IDisposable/77f11c6f7693f9d181bb).