# Convert ASP.NET webform to multiple ASP.NET MVC projects

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, webforms

I have a webform project that i will rebuild and convert to a new MVC project. When i do this, i want to separate pages in smaller projects.
This is what i have in my webform project.

Website:

- Admin
- Blog
- Groups
- Index.aspx
- Login.aspx
- Create.aspx

Now, i think to create a new separate projects for each, Admin, Blog, Groups and Startpage/Main site.

My questions is:

1. Should i create a virtual application on my host for each of my projects and then publish, or is there a better way to do this?
2. I want to route for example www....com/12 or www....com/myblog to folder Blog. Will there be any problem to do this?
3. Is it posible to link files(Web.config, Global.asax, Js-files) from Startpage/Main site to the other/sub projects? What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Can you give us justification for different projects?  It seems like using MVC areas might suffice, but you seem to be set on separate projects, need to know why.

Comment: I really don't think you need separate projects for your new mvc solution. If webforms can hold your app in a single project, mvc can do this too, definitely. It is only a matter of your routing definitions.

Comment: Thanx. Would it not be more structured if I divide it into smaller projects than to have everything in one big project? I can update only a part of the page. I have read this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/307467
But i dont know whats best to do =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mrcode, I think you'll find that MVC architecture suites multiple developers well.  A controller for each of your proposed topics will be a great container for keeping development efforts separate, and if you really needed more segregation you could look at using Areas, which group topics even more.  Areas are really just for very large projects though, so you should be fine with a typical MVC approach.  I think the extra complexity of separate projects will only work against you in both short and long term.  Good luck.

Comment: You should also note that it is possible to configure [each area on a different domain (or subdomain)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278668/is-it-possible-to-make-an-asp-net-mvc-route-based-on-a-subdomain) and really make it look from the outside like multiple applications.