# Domain and subdomain with common code in ASP.NET MVC and Azure

Tags: c#, azure, architecture, dns, asp.net-core

I have a scenario very particular in a project... and I don't know what is the best way to get it work. To set in context, imaging we are programming a TODO Web App in ASP.NET MVC 6 (ASP.NET 5) and hosting in Azure like "[Application Web"](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/web/).

We are going to have two sites:

Firs Site:
**www.mytododomain.com**

This website is just for a landing page (marketing typical), but it need to have a register and login page. When the user make login or register, he is redirect to the next website.

Second Site: **app.mytododomain.com**

This place is when you create your TODO things, you can create, edit, delete, **register**, **login** and **logoff**. And the most important, you can share your TODO lists.

When you share a TODO lists, I need to share a link with the *world* like this:

> mytododomain.com/share/{guid}

**Relevant technical information:**

- I'm using Identity 3.0.
- I am using cooking authentication and sharing the cookie between the subdomain and domain (this will be another goal!!).
- I need to have two different web projects in my solution and deploy them on two differents Azure Application Web

**The reason of that:**

We want to have differents code, and different project, because if we deploy a new version of the main **www.mytododomain.con** web, we wont want to deploy the code **app.mytodomain.com**

What is the best way to do that?

Thank you so much!!

Comment: Check this question, may resolve part of your question using custom routing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278668/is-it-possible-to-make-an-asp-net-mvc-route-based-on-a-subdomain#

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you are using IIS since you are using .Net.

If your domain and subdomain are going to point to different applications in IIS, then you should definitely have two different applications in your codebase. What I mean by this is that you should have two completely different solutions as these are two different applications.

If you need to share components between the two applications I recommend using a package manager to do so such as NuGet. This will allow you to have two decoupled applications making deployment of one not dependent on changes in the other.

As far as IIS is concerned, you can use [IIS Bindings](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites/site/bindings/binding) to have users of **www.mytododomain.com** go to one IIS hosted application and users of **app.mytodomain.com** go to another.