# Multi level sub Domains for a Multi-tenant Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing, multi-tenant

A project I am working on was once an internal intranet application, but now it is being ported over to a multi-tenant internet application. Usually, when deploying any web applications, we would use the format `http://webapp.company.com` which has existed long before I joined.
Since the project is now a multi tenant application, I am trying to decide between different architectures.

1) Using the client/tenant as part of the main host url

```
http://tenant.webapp.company.com
```

This approach requires additional ssl certificates and iis settings

2) Include the tenant as part of the routing and the tenant name will be included as a routing parameter

```
http://webapp.company.com/{tenant}/my/route/url/{param}
```

This approach, in my opinion, is 'messy' and I feel it is not the most-correct solution.

3) Keep the existing url of `http://webapp.company.com` and add specific bindings in IIS to point the requested url to the host location.

When the user enters the url `http://tenant.company.com` they will be served the application that resides at `http://webapp.company.com` The problem with this approach is that we may deploy additional applications and this is not scalable.

I am leaning towards approach number 1 as I have experience implementing it (without the extra domain). Is the 4th level domain ideal? Any ideas as to what approach is better than the other? Possibly a new approach? Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Using the client/tenant as part of the main host url
>
> http://tenant.webapp.company.com
>
> This approach requires additional ssl certificates and iis settings

Actually, you might be able to use a [wildcard certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_certificate) for `*.webapp.company.com`, which would mean you can extend this scheme without additional IIS configuration.

In addition, this approach is the most elegant when it comes to routing. There is even a [MVC-Subdomain-Routing](https://github.com/sugendran/MVC-Subdomain-Routing) project on GitHub that you can use for some direction (or as is if your requirements are met by the project).

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278668/is-it-possible-to-make-an-asp-net-mvc-route-based-on-a-subdomain) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35441583/mvc-custom-routing-subdomain/35464970#35464970) for some other approaches.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was always leaning towards the sub-domain option as it is the most elegant, but unfortunately the IT dept aren't too keen on doing work so that approach is unavailable. I am going to store it in the user db table to avoid having to include the client in the URL. Thanks again.