# Enable Subdomain routing on ASP.NET MVC area

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, routes, subdomain

My requirement is I have the login screen to log in to my site with the url, let's say `www.domain.com/login` then logged in user is a admin user route should be `admin.domain.com` admin portal implements on separate mvc area if the user is non admin then it should redirect to `portal.domain.com` which implement portal area also for non admin users strictly should not be allow to get in to admin area which I can handle with identity.

[This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278668/is-it-possible-to-make-an-asp-net-mvc-route-based-on-a-subdomain)
has nice explanation how to implement sub domain routing. I have tried with this code

```
public class ExampleRoute : RouteBase
{

    public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var url = httpContext.Request.Headers["HOST"];
        var index = url.IndexOf(".");

        if (index < 0)
            return null;

        var subDomain = url.Substring(0, index);

        if (subDomain == "admin")
        {
            var routeData = new RouteData(this, new MvcRouteHandler());
            routeData.Values.Add("controller", "admin"); //Goes to the AdminController class
            routeData.Values.Add("action", "Index"); //Goes to the Index action on the AdminController
            routeData.DataTokens.Add("area", "Admin");  

            return routeData;
        }

        if (subDomain == "portal")
        {
            var routeData = new RouteData(this, new MvcRouteHandler());
            routeData.Values.Add("controller", "portal"); //Goes to the PortalController class
            routeData.Values.Add("action", "Index"); //Goes to the Index action on the PortalController
            routeData.DataTokens.Add("area", "Portal");
            return routeData;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
    {
        //Implement your formating Url formating here
        return null;
    }
}
```

but i'm not sure how to apply that implementation to my scenario. how to come up with above implementation support to my requirement.

**Update**
 I have added the subdomain routing in to the route collection

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.LowercaseUrls = true;
    routes.Add(new SubDomainRoute());
    routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new
    {
        controller = "Home",
        action = "Index",
        id = UrlParameter.Optional
    },namespaces: new[] { " SmartMeter.Portal.Controllers" });

}
```

and Area registered like this

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "Admin_default",
        "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        new[] { "SmartMeter.Portal.Areas.Admin.Controllers" }
    );
}
```

but then I get this error

[image]

Comment: Try `routes.Add(new SubdomainRoute())` on `RegisterRoutes` method, you need to include subdomain routing before default routing. Show your current routing scenario if necessary.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I have edited question could you please have a look.

Comment: Clean your solution first by deleting project's main DLL file (same as project name) if exists. Ensure you have `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()` method registered on `Application_Start`, then make sure project namespace and project name matches.

Comment: yeah i did all problem was url match to `admin.domain.com/admin` not `admin.domain.com` how to avoid having area sub from url  `/Admin`

Comment: To treat `admin` part as subdomain rather than controller part, probably you may try example steps on Tony's blog here: http://blog.tonywilliams.me.uk/asp-net-mvc-2-routing-subdomains-to-areas/. You need to capture host name pattern using `GetVirtualPath` method and redirect to area route using `GetRouteData` there.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto i have tried that solution as well but no luck

Comment: From reading the error looks like you are using the home controller in all your areas, without an overload i cant see this working, Try renaming the Admin area controller to admin and create the routes for it, same for the portal.