# How to generate an URL from a route template in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-routing

I have two separate ASP.NET Core sites `A1` and `A2` based on a same shared library `B`.

`A1` and `A2` are on a1.example.com and a2.example.com, and they have controllers with route templates looking like

`A1`:

```
[HttpGet("/Feature1/{featureId}/EditEntry/{entryId}", Name = "EditFeature1Entry")]
public IActionResult EditFeature1Entry(long featureId, Guid entryId, string token)
{
    [...]
}
```

In project `A1`, I would generate an URL using

```
var url = Url.RouteUrl("EditFeature1Entry", new {featureId = 3, entryId = someGuid, token})
```

it would generate:

```
url = "/Feature1/3/EditEntry/someGuid?token=token"
```

But to build the same url from `A2`, I need to generate the URL myself as the route is not registered in the project `A2` (the controller is in project `A1`).

**What I would like to do** is to put the templates somewhere in the library `B` and use an URL generator to be able to do something like

```
var url = Url.RouteUrlFromTemplate("/Feature1/{featureId}/EditEntry/{entryId}", new {featureId = 3, entryId = someGuid, token}, "https", "a1.example.com", null);
```

in order to generate

```
url = "https://a1.example.com/Feature1/3/EditEntry/someGuid?token=token"
```

Is there any pre-built tool for that or should I do it myself? 
I feel I could use a large part of what exists in the current Url builder, but I would prefer to rely on the framework :)

Answer (score 0):

But it seems your two sites are two subdomains of a domain and you can see this links too:
https://www.crookm.com/journal/2018/routing-by-subdomain-in-asp-net-core-mvc/

[Is it possible to make an ASP.NET MVC route based on a subdomain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278668/is-it-possible-to-make-an-asp-net-mvc-route-based-on-a-subdomain)

[https://forums.asp.net/t/2106373.aspx?Enable+Subdomain+routing+on+ASP+NET+MVC+area](https://forums.asp.net/t/2106373.aspx?Enable%20Subdomain%20routing%20on%20ASP%20NET%20MVC%20area)

And it is a subdomain routing project in github:

https://github.com/mariuszkerl/AspNetCoreSubdomain

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however most of these use Controller/Action/... standard route. I would like a solution for any custom route template, not especially registered, that could be part of another site.
The `RouteUrlFromTemplate` tool does not exist, that is a method I would like to have.

Comment: Subdomains are on different sites

Comment: I'm so sorry! Why you don't trying to  make the RouteUrlFromTemplate as a new routing tool?